Export / import variables in different files
I have a function in func.js. And I also have some variables in vars.js.
How can I export variables from vars.js to func.js to use these variables within function in func.js?
I tried this case:
vars.js:
let var1 = "test1";
let var2 = "test2";
export { var1, var2};

func.js
import { var1, var2 } from '../vars.js';

index.cshtml:
<script type="module" src="~/vars.js" defer></script>
<script type="module" src="~/func.js" defer></script>

If I'm trying to log var1 and var2 to the console I get an error:

SyntaxError: Export 'moduleNum' is not defined in module

Please advise me how to export variables from one JS file to another?

Just FYI, when asking a question about a code problem the IDE you're using is not in any way relevant. I've removed the references you had to VS22

Is vars.js and func.js in the same folder? If so you should write ./var.js instead of ../var.js.

The "~/func.js" and "~/var.js" in your script tag might also be a mistake. You should just write scr="func.js"

try exporting this way:
module.exports = {var1, var2}

then try importing this way:
const {var1, var2} = require("../vars.js")

